# Add page to menu programmatically after creation

Tags: php, wordpress, menu, nav

I have been trying to figure this out for hours and I've had no luck. I know it's something easy that I'm missing, but I cannot find it anywhere on StackOverflow.

What I want to is add the page that is being created here to either the existing menu (which will be blank), or remove the current menu, create a new menu and add the page that way, whichever is easier.

Here is the code I'm using to add a page (and editing / saving) from a plugin interface:

```
$titlep2 = $_REQUEST['titlep2'];
$post_text2 = $_REQUEST['post_text2'];
if($titlep2 != ""){
$posthwe_id2 = get_option("hwepag2");
    if($posthwe_id2 == ""){ 
        $hwea2 = array('post_title' => $titlep2,
                       'post_content' => $post_text2,
                       'post_status' => 'publish',
                       'post_type' => 'page');
        $post_idp2 = wp_insert_post($hwea2);
        update_option("hwepag2",$post_idp2);
    }else{
        $my_post2 = array('ID'           => $posthwe_id2,
                          'post_title'   => $titlep2,
                          'post_content' => $post_text2,
        );
        wp_update_post( $my_post2 );
    }
}
```

I have tried many variations of wp_update_nav_menu_item, but I cannot get it to work. I have an existing menu, but it will be blank when adding this post (this is for new/fresh sites that I develop offline). That being the case, it seems the menuID, which is "menu-top" does not exist in the UL before adding an element to the menu.

So, it's fine if the current menu needs to be deleted, a new one created, then the page I'm adding added to that menu.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Try this if not already done:
Go to Appearance > Menus > Select your menu if you have multiple of them > Check the checkbox down below that says "Automatically add new top-level pages to this menu"

Comment: Sorry but that's not a viable solution... I'm adding multiple pages at once to my development sites automatically, including a home/front page and I want to specify which one is added. It's only the "Contact" page that I want added. But that contact page will have a different "page ID" and potentially name every time. Which is why it must be identified and added at the time of creation.

Comment: Okay, then try checking out this link : https://gist.github.com/eduwass/4dc3f4522f6a91d033d4

Comment: Already tried, it didn't work for me... plus since the menu is empty at the time of page creation, $menu_id    NavMenu ID... I don't think it has a menu ID. There's nothing in the source (in the UL), only when there are items in the menu does it have an ID.